# Can't get POST data with AJAX

Tags: ajax, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.1

I would like to show 4 objects in a page, with a "load more" button which show 4 more object each time we click.

I try to adapt a PHP script which works(tested) to Symfony. 
The problem is that I can't get the POST data (a page number) in my Symfony function, even if I can see it in the chrome developer toolbar...

[image: POST variable with key 'page' and value '1']
My controller:

```
<?php
/**
 * Content controller.
 *
 * @Route("content")
 */
class ContentController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all software.
 *
 * @Route("/software", name="content_software")
 * @Method({"POST", "GET"})
 */
public function softwareAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->request->get('page')){
        $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
                FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
        $item_per_page = 4;
        $position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
        $contents = $this->getRepo()->findBy(array(),null,$item_per_page,$position);
    }
    else
    {
        $contents = "didn't work";
    }
    return $this->render('content/index.html.twig', array(
            'contents' => $contents
    ));
}
}
```

index.html.twig :

{% extends 'loicCoreBundle::Default/layout.html.twig' %}

```
{% block body %}
{{ dump(contents) }}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var track_page = 1; //track user click as page number, right now page number is 1
    load_contents(track_page); //load content

    $("#load_more_button").click(function (e) { //user clicks on button
        track_page++; //page number increment everytime user clicks load button
        load_contents(track_page); //load content
    });

        //Ajax load function
        function load_contents(track_page){

            $.post( "{{ path('content_software') }}", {'page': track_page}, function(data){

                if(data.trim().length == 0){
                    //display text and disable load button if nothing to load
                    $("#load_more_button").text("No more records!").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        }           
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where your errors are coming from, I've done a similar test which just works (no problems with `$request->request->get()`).

You are however loading a full template (index.html) for each sub request as well. Usually you want to separate calls like this into api like methods, however for simple things its a bit silly.

Here is an expanded/ updated version of what I tested, I avoided post data all together and just used the method as switch. This worked fine so try and figure out where you went wrong using this as reflection (or whatever you like to do with it). Note this uses a simple PHP range array for test data, not entities but it should remain the same principle.

#### Controller

```
    /**
     * @Route(
     *      "software/{page}/{limit}",
     *      name="content_software",
     *      requirements = {
     *          "page": "[1-9]\d*",
     *          "limit": "[1-9]\d*"
     *      }
     * )
     */
    public function softwareAction(Request $request, $page = 1, $limit = 4) {
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            // replace these two lines with database logic (SELECT & LIMIT)
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
            $items = array_slice(range(1, 10), $start, $limit); // Just using a simple item array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] as test data

            $content = '';
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $content .= $this->get('twig')->render('someItemTemplate.html.twig', ['item' => $item]);
            }

            return new Response($content);
        } else {
            // alternatively you can send out the default items here for the first get request
            // and use the same item template above with {% embed %} to render them in this template
            return $this->render('someTemplate.html.twig');
        }
    }
```

#### someTemplate.html.twig

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cake or death?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="put-the-things-here"></ul>
        <button id="next_please">Ehh cake please!</button>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var pageTracker = 1,
                $next = $("#next_please"),
                $target = $('#put-the-things-here');

            load_contents(pageTracker);

            $next.click(function (e) {
                load_contents(++pageTracker);
            });

            function load_contents(page) {
                // using post just for the request method (page is in the url)
                $.post("{{ path('content_software') }}/" + page,
                    function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            $target.append(data);
                        } else {
                            $target.append('<li>We are out of cake.</li>');
                            $next.attr('disabled', true);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### someItemTemplate.twig

```
<li>Cake: {{ item }}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$request->request->get('page')
```

Instead of this:

```
$request->request->has('page')
```

If it doesn't work try to:

```
var_dump($request->request->all());
```

And check the variables

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work too ;) .

And has is in the doc too. 

"has()
Returns true if the parameter is defined."

Comment: What does it mean not works? Which error do you retrieve?

Comment: Sorry, it returns NULL.

Comment: It's empty :-/.

Comment: How are you checking these cause i'm starting to think its something else (and there are a few things there)

Comment: Try tom remove GET from the annotation please @L01C

Comment: / if your are checking the twig dump it will always fail, cause you are basically using `isset(true)`

Comment: @JennevanderMeer The isset is not the problem, I gave me an error before and I deleted it ;) . When I test it, I don't even enter in my if, I just try it before with "     $test=  $request->request->get('page');" and dump it in twig. 
It was just a way to make my code clear.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I tried, but it gives me an error "loic\ContentBundle\Entity\Content object not found.
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException". :-/

Comment: Uhm very strange, so try to make another route with only post and call it from your ajax please @L01C

Comment: As long as you are sending them along ->render('template', ['test' => $test]); - ok, if not you need to expose the var to twig like as described..

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I tried with an other bundle to only use "POST" and got this error :
"No route found for "GET /filter/testfilter": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)". 

As if it was impossible to specify only POST method to a function.

Comment: I think you have configured wrong the route because usually you have a route for post one for get

Answer (score 0):

I think too the problem comes from routes.
Error message when I use only "POST" method :

"No route found for "GET /content/software": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST, DELETE)".
Because when I arrive on my page by clicking a link , I arrive with a GET method.

However, when I click on my "load more" button the AJAX works and I can see in my symfony debugbar that I get POST variable: 
[image: Post variable]

The problem is when I first arrive on my page I think.

@Jenne van der Meer: Thank you but I would like not to use GET parameters.

I add my full controller code, in case of:

```
/**
 * Content controller.
 *
 * @Route("content")
 */
class ContentController extends Controller
{
    public function getRepo(){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('loicContentBundle:Content');

        return $repo;
    }

//  private $theRepo = getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('loicContentBundle:Content');

    /**
     * Lists all content entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="content_index")
     * @Method("GET")    */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $contents = $this->getRepo()->findAll();
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

                $formFilter = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('_',     EntityType::class,array(
                                'class' => 'loicFilterBundle:Filter',
                                'multiple' => true,
                                'expanded' => true,
                                'choice_label' => function($value) {
                                return ($value->getName());
                                },
                                ))
                        ->add('Appliquer filtres', SubmitType::class)

                                ->getForm();

                                $formFilter->handleRequest($request);
                                $data = '';
                                if ($formFilter->isSubmitted() && $formFilter->isValid()) {
                                    $data = $formFilter->getData();
                                    $data = $data['_']->toArray();

                                    $contents = $this->getRepo()->findAll();
                                }
                                else
                                    {$contents = $this->getRepo()->findAll();
                                    }

        return $this->render('content/index.html.twig', array(
                'contents' => $contents,'formFilter' => $formFilter->createView(),'request' => $request
        ));
    }

    public function contentAction($categoryId)
    {   
        $contents= $this->getRepo()->findBy(
                array('contentCategorycontentCategory' => $categoryId),
                null,
                4

                );  
        return $contents;
    }

    /**
     * Lists all software.
     *
     * @Route("/software", name="content_software")
     */
    public function softwareAction(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump($request->request->all());
        $bla =  $request->request->get('page');
        if ($request->request->get('page')){
            $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
                    FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
            $item_per_page = 4;
            $position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
            $contents = $this->getRepo()->findBy(array(),null,$item_per_page,$position);
        }
        else
        {
            $contents = "didn't work";
        }
        return $this->render('content/index.html.twig', array(
                'contents' => $contents,'bla' => $bla
        ));

    }


    /**
     * Lists all videos.
     *
     * @Route("/videos", name="content_videos")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function videoAction()
    {
        $contents = $this->contentAction(5);
        return $this->render('content/index.html.twig', array(
                'contents' => $contents,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all testimonies.
     *
     * @Route("/testimonies", name="content_testimonies")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function testimoniesAction()
    {
        $contents = $this->contentAction(8);
        return $this->render('content/index.html.twig', array(
                'contents' => $contents,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all whiteBooks.
     *
     * @Route("/whiteBooks", name="content_whiteBooks")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function whiteBooksAction()
    {
        $contents = $this->contentAction(3);
        return $this->render('content/index.html.twig', array(
                'contents' => $contents,
        ));
    }



    /**
     * Lists all actuality.
     *
     * @Route("/actuality", name="content_actuality")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function actualityAction()
    {
        $contents = $this->contentAction(6);
        return $this->render('content/index.html.twig', array(
                'contents' => $contents,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all webinar.
     *
     * @Route("/webinar", name="content_webinar")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function webinarAction()
    {
        $contents = $this->contentAction(4);
        return $this->render('content/index.html.twig', array(
                'contents' => $contents,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all blog posts.
     *
     * @Route("/blog", name="content_blog")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function blogAction()
    {
        $contents = $this->contentAction(7);
        return $this->render('content/index.html.twig', array(
                'contents' => $contents,
        ));
    }


    /**
     * Creates a new content entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="content_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {   
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $content = new Content();
        $form = $this->createForm('loic\ContentBundle\Form\ContentType', $content);        
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($content);
            $em->flush($content);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('content_show', array('id' => $content->getIdcontent()));
        }

        return $this->render('content/new.html.twig', array(
            'content' => $content,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }



    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing content entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="content_edit")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Content $content)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($content);
        $editForm = $this->createForm('loic\ContentBundle\Form\ContentType', $content);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('content_edit', array('id' => $content->getIdcontent()));
        }

        return $this->render('content/edit.html.twig', array(
            'content' => $content,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a content entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="content_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, Content $content)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($content);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($content);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('content_index');
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a content entity.
     *
     * @param Content $content The content entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Content $content)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('content_delete', array('id' => $content->getIdcontent())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

My Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml file is empty.